# MySQL: Error 1055 When attempting to Return Count of Referrer by Month in Year 2020

Tags: mysql, date, workbench

I'm getting the following error code:

Error Code: 1055. Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'usergrowthhomework.weblogs.day' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

This code is a result of me attempting to run the following query, which is supposed to return the number of times a 'referrer' appears each month in the year 2020:

```
SELECT MONTH(day) MONTH, referrer, COUNT(referrer) AS cumulative_pageviews
FROM weblogs
WHERE YEAR(day) >= '2020'
GROUP BY MONTH(day), referrer
ORDER BY day, referrer;
```

My table's columns look like this:

user_no - int
name - varchar(200)
referrer - varchar(200)
start_date - timestamp
day - date

Can anyone explain why I'm getting such an error? I clearly included all appropriate expressions in the GROUP BY and SELECT clauses.

I'm using the MySQL workbench to run this query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error suggests, the `day` column in the `order by` clause isn't in the `group by` clause, and thus can't be used there. You should order by `MONTH(day)` instead:

```sql
SELECT   MONTH(day) MONTH, referrer, COUNT(referrer) AS cumulative_pageviews
FROM     weblogs
WHERE    YEAR(day) >= 2020
GROUP BY MONTH(day), referrer
ORDER BY MONTH(day), referrer;
-- Here -^
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much! I was just following a tutorial from popsql.com and they weren't clear on requiring this MONTH(day) be in all 'by' clauses.  Now I will remember this!